# How do i pass an event value to a React state in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, react-hooks

I have an input element listening to an event, how do I pass the value of the input to a React State?

```
const [business, setBusiness] = useState('Value should be entered here')

<input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange={"pass the value"}/>
```

Comment: You should read the [`useState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) documentation so you understand how it works. `useState` returns an array. The first element is the state. The second element is the function that sets the state. So you need to call the function with the input value to set the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
<input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange={e => setBusiness(e.target.value)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One can set value in useState by setting event value like this :

```
<input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange={event => setBusiness(event.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).